# Create Dictionary List from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, list

This is the sample XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test plan_name="test">
  <Big bro="S7" sys="lolipop">
      <Work name="first"></Work>
      <Work name="second"></Work>
  </Big>
  <Big bro="S6" sys="kitkat">
      <Work name="trird"></Work>
      <Work name="fourth"></Work>
  </Big>
</Test>
```

My target is to create dictionary with each work name and keep it in a list.

This is my sample code:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(line[0].rstrip()+'/stack.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

total=[]

for child in root.findall('Big'):
  test=child.attrib
  for children in child:    
    test.update(children.attrib)
    total.append(test)
print total
```

Expected output:

> [{'bro': 'S7', 'sys': 'lolipop', 'name': 'first'}, {'bro': 'S7', 'sys': 'lolipop', 'name': 'second'}, {'bro': 'S6', 'sys': 'kitkat', 'name': 'third'}, {'bro': 'S6', 'sys': 'kitkat', 'name': 'fourth'}]

But My Output looks like this:

> [{'bro': 'S7', 'sys': 'lolipop', 'name': 'second'}, {'bro': 'S7', 'sys': 'lolipop', 'name': 'second'}, {'bro': 'S6', 'sys': 'kitkat', 'name': 'fourth'}, {'bro': 'S6', 'sys': 'kitkat', 'name': 'fourth'}]

Help me out please.
Thank you

Comment: What is the `ET` variable? `ElementTree`?

Comment: yes. import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET will be above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify your `test` dict in-place which result in a modification of the previously inserted reference in total as well.
It should work by creating a copy of it before updating it:

```
...
for child in root.findall('Big'):
  test=child.attrib
  for children in child:    
    testCopy = dict(test)
    testCopy.update(children.attrib)
    total.append(testCopy)
print(total)
...
```